# I need a button on the edit page to change attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails. In my project, I have a task controller and a tasks table with a column name `task_status`. When task is saved, the status is set to `open`. Now, I want to place a `mark closed` button on the edit view page to set the status to `closed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways. One way would be to include a check box, named `close_task` in your form. When this check box is checked and the form is submitted, you check for `param[:close_task]`.

So for example:

```
def update
  if param[:close_task]
    @task.status = 'closed'
    @task.save
  end
  ...
end
```